# Sitecore 8.2 Update 1 folder and files gone missing

Tags: azure

Noticed that after standing up 8.2 updates 1 on Web App, the following folders and files are not there anymore.

**Folder:**

1. Media Cache
2. Submit Queue
3. MediaIndexing

**Files:**

Log files are missing ( I'm aware that log details appear on app insight, but is it possible to dump the log files on to azure blob storage?)

Curious to understand how Sitecore has tackled the Web App single file share issue.

Comment: Can you visit /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx and see what this set to. It sounds like it got moved in 8.2u1

<sc.variable name="dataFolder" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\XXXX\Data"/>

Answer (score 3):

As dnstommy mentions in the comments, you should be able to find your data folder on the showconfig page. The Data folder is now (by default at least) under the webroot/App_Data folder.

I'm not sure when the Application Insights wouldn't be enough for the log files, but if you want to query the log files in more detail, on the Application Insights there's an 'Analytics' button as well.

[image: Analytics button in Application Insights]

That will open a new window where you can write a query such as:

```
traces
| where severityLevel == 3
```

That particular query will get you all entries in your log files that are logged as `ERROR`.

I've created a blog post which mentions some other cool things we can do with Application Insights and Sitecore's performance stats as well [here](https://trayek.wordpress.com/2016/12/07/application-insights-for-sitecore-or-where-have-my-logfiles-gone/).